# How can I get 'KeyDown' without writing 26 commands?

Tags: dynamic, keyboard, eventhandler, input

`EventHandler` and `{"KeyDown","x"}` work for registering a specific letter. Is there a direct way to return whichever letter keys are pressed?

Comment: See ``CurrentValue["EventKey"]``

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps something like this?:

```
DynamicModule[{key = ""}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[key],
  {"KeyDown" :> (key = CurrentValue["EventKey"])}
 ]]
```